# Comparing two html documents with different ordering of attributes etc in Java

Tags: javascript, java, html, compare, jsoup

I have a use case where I need to compare two html documents with subtle differences such as this

Snippet from the first doc

```
<p>Hello</p><span style="width:100%; height50%"></span>
```

Snippet from the second doc

```
<p>Hello</p><span style="height50%;width:100%"></span>
```

And there are many other issues when comparing like the ordering of the attributes, whitespaces etc.

Is there a library in Java (or at least in javascript) like Jsoup that can help me do this or can someone come up with one? Thanks.

Comment: why do you need that? and why white-spaces matter for your case? why just normal compare not working for you?

Comment: normal compare fails in the above example because the ordering of height and width are different in both cases. So comparison fails even though the ordering is different, the view generated by the two are the same. They should compare as equals in this context!

Comment: If the html document was limited to the snippets depicted in the post, what would you expect?

Comment: I still think you need to explain the purpose of this. Nothing will understand your doc (and all its linked JS and CSS files, which are every bit as important as your static markup) better than an actual browser, but is it visual, functional, or lexical differences you're interested in? And what about tolerances? I think this is a much broader topic than your post suggests.

Comment: @AndrewRegan I just need to compare two html documents programatically. Irrespective of any js/css references, I just need to compare the two DOM trees.